# I want to get orderID from API response using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, web-api-testing, data-driven-tests

I want to get the order ID from the API response. When I click on the Create Order button it will send a POST API request and return the unique ID that I want.

This is my order creation code.

```
from datetime import date
import time
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from Locators.PracticeLocators import PracticeLocators
from pageObjects.LoginPage import LoginScreen

today = date.today()
currentDate = today.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
FilePath = "C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProject/LegrandePython/TestData/Data.xlsx"
datafile = load_workbook(FilePath)
testData = datafile['Test Data']
loginData = datafile["Login Credentials"]
scriptData = datafile["Script Data"]

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()

driver.scopes = [
    '.*https://ibis-dev.droicelabs.us/api/dispenser/orders/.*'
]

driver.get(loginData.cell(4, 2).value)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
login = LoginScreen(driver)
login.SetUsername(loginData.cell(4, 3).value)
login.SetPassword(loginData.cell(4, 4).value)
login.SignIn()
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.find_element_by_class_name(PracticeLocators.Add_RX).click()
PatientSearch = driver.find_element_by_xpath(PracticeLocators.Patient_search_textbox)
PatientSearch.click()
PatientSearch.send_keys(testData.cell(2, 1).value)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//*[text()='" + testData.cell(2, 2).value + "'])[1]").click()
DoctorSearch = driver.find_element_by_xpath(PracticeLocators.doctor_search_textbox)
DoctorSearch.click()
time.sleep(1)
DoctorSearch.send_keys(scriptData.cell(2, 8).value)
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "(//*[text()='" + scriptData.cell(2, 8).value + " " + "Practice'])[2]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(PracticeLocators.NextButton).click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(PracticeLocators.CreateOnetimeRXButton).click()
driver.find_element_by_name(PracticeLocators.OnetimeSearchMedicine).send_keys(scriptData.cell(2, 1).value)
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='" + scriptData.cell(2, 1).value + "']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(PracticeLocators.AddButton).click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(PracticeLocators.ProductQuantity).click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(PracticeLocators.Quantity).click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(PracticeLocators.ProductRefilles).click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(PracticeLocators.Quantity).click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(PracticeLocators.DAWCheckbox).click()
time.sleep(2)
instruction = driver.find_element_by_xpath(PracticeLocators.productInstruction)
instruction.click()
instruction.send_keys(testData.cell(2, 3).value)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(PracticeLocators.allergiesButton).click()
allergies = driver.find_element_by_xpath(PracticeLocators.allergiesTextbox)
allergies.clear()
allergies.send_keys(testData.cell(2, 4).value)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(PracticeLocators.doneButton).click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(PracticeLocators.addDropchartButton).click()
time.sleep(2)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(PracticeLocators.selectDocuments)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", element)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(PracticeLocators.selectButton).click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(PracticeLocators.skipPayment).click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(PracticeLocators.surgeryDate).send_keys(currentDate)
createOrderButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath(PracticeLocators.submit_CreateOrderButton)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", createOrderButton)
for request in driver.requests:
    if request.response:
        print(
            request.url,
            request.response.status_code,
            request.response.headers['Content-Type'])
time.sleep(7)
```

When `self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", createOrderButton)` this line execute it will send the POST API `https://ibis-dev.droicelabs.us/api/dispenser/orders/` and return unique order id that I want.

I have give scope but it will return many API call

```
driver.scopes = [
    '.*https://ibis-dev.droicelabs.us/api/dispenser/orders/.*'
]
```

`https://ibis-dev.droicelabs.us/api/dispenser/orders/` this API will call when I click on the create order button and return order id.
It will not show the API that I have used in a scope. And how to get the response of that API which I have given in scope.
I am new to selenium python and I have done it in cypress. but don't know how to do it using selenium python.

Answer (score 3):

This is how to capture HTTP requests using Selenium:

1 Install package

```
pip install selenium-wire
```

2 Use `driver.requests` to get some data

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# do you actions with driver

for request in driver.requests:  
    if request.response:  
        print(  
            request.url,  
            request.response.status_code,  
            request.response.headers['Content-Type'])
```

3 You might want to limit requests capture to some specific hosts

https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/#limiting-request-capture

```
driver.scopes = [
    '.*ibis-dev.droicelabs.us/api/dispenser/orders/.*'
]
```

4 How to read response body

```
import json

...

    for request in driver.requests:
        if request.response:
            data = json.loads(request.response.body)
            print(data['foo'])
```

**Answering this question - get order id**

The final solution for getting order_id for multiple portals which handles `UnicodeDecodeError`, `JSONDecodeError` errors and prints some debug details:

```py
#define scopes to capture the required requests
driver.scopes = [
    '.*/api/dispenser/orders/.*',
    '.*/api/practice/orders/.*',
    '.*/api/practice/subscriptions/.*'
]


# UI steps performed...

# The last UI action
createOrderButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath(PracticeLocators.submit_CreateOrderButton)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", createOrderButton)
time.sleep(5)

order_id = None
# read requests for order_id
for request in driver.requests:
    if request.response:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            print(request.method + ' ' + request.url)
            try:
                data = json.loads(request.response.body)
                print('parsed as json')
                if '_id' in data:
                    order_id = data['_id']
            except UnicodeDecodeError:
                try:
                    data = json.loads(decompress(request.response.body))
                    print('decompressed and parsed as json')
                    if '_id' in data:
                        order_id = data['_id']
                except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
                    data = request.response.body
                    print('decompressed and parsed as string')
print(data)
print(order_id)
```

**Limitations**

> Selenium Wire will currently work with tests that run on the same machine as the browser. A distributed setup using Selenium Grid is not yet supported.

> Sites that use NTLM authentication (Windows authentication) cannot currently be tested with Selenium Wire. NTLM authentication is not supported.

---

**Reference**

https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/

Comment: It not working getting `AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'requests'` in `for request in self.driver.requests:` this line.

Comment: What import do you use? `from selenium import webdriver` or `from seleniumwire import webdriver`?

Comment: I have use `from seleniumwire import webdriver`

Comment: This error is related to your implementation, since the pure example I've provided works well. I've rechecked.. The error `AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'requests'` means you have some 'WebDriver' object in this field, but it's not a seleniumwire WebDriver. Try to print `print(type(self.driver))`

Comment: @KrupalVaghasiya also you have to use the local webdriver, not remote.. I've updated the answer with limitations section.

Comment: Please check the question I have updated.

Comment: @KrupalVaghasiya I see, try to remove https from scope, leave `'.*ibis-dev.droicelabs.us/api/dispenser/orders/.*'`.

Comment: If i remove `https` test will pass but it doesn't show `https://ibis-dev.droicelabs.us/api/dispenser/orders/` this API

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241273/discussion-between-max-daroshchanka-and-krupal-vaghasiya).

Comment: Hi Max, I am getting errors sometime for the same `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte` for this line `order_id = json.loads(self.driver.requests[-1].response.body)["_id"]`